# Identification of a small mammal

Tags: zoology, species-identification, mammals

Could someone help with identification of this small mammal? Is it a possum? A dormouse?

It was photographed in Sukhumi botanical garden, in Abkhazia (west of Georgia, on the shores of the black sea).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a marsupial such as an opossum, since no marsupials are native to the region. It looks to be a rodent of some kind, probably a species in the [Muridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muridae) family.

Which species is it is exactly is hard to tell, since there are many species in Muridae which look quite similar, but my best guess is that this is a [**Tamarisk jird**](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/13169/0). It could also conceivably be an escaped domestic gerbil or some type of mouse. The one that you found has more pronounced light areas on its coat than the photographs I found, but is within reasonable limits of what variation can be expected.

Here are some of the few pictures I was able to find that I could verify were of this species.

[image]

<sup>*Klaus Rudloff* ([source](http://www.biolib.cz/en/image/id175454/))</sup>

[image]

<sup>*Klaus Rudloff* ([source](http://www.biolib.cz/en/image/id175450/))</sup>